# How to Parse HTML using php?

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have following HTML file

```
 <body>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="book">
       <b>Book Name:</b></br>
       <span class="bookname"> Name of the Book </span></br>
       <b>Summary:</b></br>
       .....
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

By parsing the above html file. I only want to print the innertext of < span > element. i.e.

```
 Name of the Book
```

I am trying to parse by using 'simple_html_dom' 3rd party plugin.

```
<?php
 include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file("html_file.html");
 echo $html->find('span[class=bookname]')->innertext;
?>
```

but the above code doesn't work. Please tell me if i did anything wrong or else you can assist me by using PHP DOM module if you know.

Comment: You would have to do better than "code doesn't work". We have no idea what that means.

Comment: I don't have simplehtmldom to test, but I would assume `find()` returns an array or collection of elements that you are meant to loop over and so there isn't an innertext property. You should try turning on error_reporting or check your error logs to see if something is being reported which it likely is.

Comment: And there ya go, if you read the documentation for `find()`, "Find elements by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise return an array of object." It's amazing what you can find in about 3 seconds of reading documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simple_html_dom` uses jQuery like (or CSS) selectors, so `find` will return an array of objects (if any).

```
echo $html->find('span[class=bookname]', 0)->innertext;
```

should work. or even better:

```
echo $html->find('span.bookname', 0)->innertext;
```